# innerHTML to ascii

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ascii

I am attempting to write my own piece of Javascript that converts html to ascii code (for learning purposes) so that the browser will render the code as you would see it in a text editor.

After looking around on Stack I have gotten as far as below. I am trying to turn an html element into a string; at this stage I am just trying to `.replace()` the angular brackets into ascii. If anyone could tell me where I am going wrong as far as having my test `<body>` tag showing up in the console that would be much appreciated.

```
<code class="lang-html">
  <body></body>
</code>

(function() {
  var html = $('.lang-html').innerHTML;
  html.replace('<', '&lt;');
  html.replace('>', '&gt;');
  console.log(html);
});
```

Just to clarify, I am expecting that the console would spit out `&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `encodeURIcomponent`, rather than using `replace`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want get  `html` code representation of an DOMElement in your browser then you won't need the `replace` to escape the html special chars. But you can use the browser to take care of all edge cases.

You could just use `innerHTML`/`outerHTML` and `textContent`.

This will e.g. will replace the content of the `body` with its `html` code representation.

```js
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
elm.textContent = elm.outerHTML;
```

Or if you just want to have the result as string but not displayed in the browsers then you could wrap that into a function:

```js
function escapeHTML(html) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = html;
  return div.innerHTML;
}

console.log( escapeHTML('<div>test</div>') );
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Are you able to show me what you mean with my example? http://jsfiddle.net/16mqxrtx/

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

```
$('.lang-html').innerHTML
```

Assuming this is jQuery, this won't work. `.innerHTML` only works on raw DOM elements, like what's returned from `document.getElementById(...)`. Instead, `$('.lang-html')` returns a **jQuery collection**, which has its own accessor methods. You should do:

```
$('.lang-html').html() // get the HTML as text from this element
```

Moving on, `.replace()` won't modify the original string. It returns a new copy. In the simplest case you can do:

```
var html = $('.lang-html')
    .html()
    .replace('<', '&lt;')
    .replace('>', '&gt;');
```

But you still have to re-assign it to the HTML source. Again, jQuery provides a simple API for this.

```
$('.lang-html').html(html);
```

However, there's one more problem. `.replace()` only replaces the first match in a string. To replace all of them, you need to construct a regex and use the `/g` (global) flag. Here's the complete code:

```
var $element = $('.lang-html');

var html = $element.html()
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

$element.html(html)
```

Comment: Thank you for this; very helpful. I'm assuming I have made even more errors if this were to be Javascript and not jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry—if I didn't want to use jQuery at all. Just straight Javascript, have I made even more errors than what you initially pointed out? As this is my intention, to use Javascript and not lean on jQuery at all.

Comment: No, you have not made more errors by using jQuery. The only thing that changes is how you've found the element (jQuery is `$(selector)` vs raw javascript DOM API `document.querySelector(selector)`), and how you assign the HTML back to the element.

Comment: That code example above isn't working for me. Is there a syntax error I'm not seeing or...?

Comment: If you run the last code block, and an element on your page with class `lang-html` is on the page, I believe it should work. If there's any syntax errors you would see them by opening the console (in Chrome) by pressing  command-option-J on mac, or control-shift-J on Windows

Comment: You should actually run your anonymous function ;) http://jsfiddle.net/16mqxrtx/1/ . Note the added `()` at the very end of the JS code to execute the fn. Also you don't need to wrap your program in an anonymous function in JSFiddle because the JS executes after the HTML is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a

```
$('.lang-html').prop("innerText")
```

which will hand you back the contents of that div, as real text.

No further translation should be needed.

Comment: Are you suggesting I swap out innerHTML for the above example from my original code?

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to, then yes.  Rather then get the HTML and turn it back into regular text, why not just get the regular text to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **<body>** tags will not be returned in the `innerHTML` of the posted code because the HTML is invalid. To explain:

To cater for changes to the DOM made in Javascript, browsers dynamically create `innerHTML` strings from the DOM by inspecting child elements of a specified node and generating HTML code from them.

Since  **<body>** tags are only valid immediately following the head section, browsers silently respond to the **<code>** tag in your post by first creating a body element in which to place it. The **<body>** tags which follow are then ignored because they are invalid in this position. Hence there is no body element child of the code node, and no body tags in its `innerHTML`

---

Update (2): To pretty print the HTML without viewing page source you could try.

```
 (function() {
      var body = document.body;
      var html = body.parentNode.outerHTML;
      html = html.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
      html = html.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
      html = html.replace(/\ /g, "&nbsp;");
      html = html.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');
      // console.log(html);
      body.innerHTML = html;
      body.style.fontFamily = "monospace";
});
```

Comment: So from what you're saying their is no way put straight html syntax into a container javascript is watching and dynamically change it to ascii so that the browser will render it as code?

Comment: Please see the second update in my answer above as a way of providing readable code. I leave it with you what elements you want to get the code for and where to render the output. @t.niese many thanks for `outerHTML`